# My link_to image_tag is not doing anything when users click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Rails beginner here.

Using the following link_to image_tag to try and allow people to click on a logo on my website, and have them get directed to the particular page.

```
.content
  - current_user.users_coupons.each do |uc|
    .logo
          = link_to image_tag(uc.coupon.drug.logo.list_item), uc.coupon, remote:true
```

The image on my site shows the correct link when you mouse over, but when you actually CLICK nothing happens - it doesn't actually take you to the URL it shows. What gives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you add `remote:true` if you want them to be redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure nothing is happening?  If you look at the "Net" tab on Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug, I am willing to bet that a request is being made, but returning a 500 error.

Adding `remote:true` to the `link_to` process the click as a ajax request so unless you specify an ajax:success callback event, nothing will appear to happen.  What is actually happening is you are doing a GET js on the targeted controller action.

Comment: Got it, thanks for explaining this. So when do you need to use it? Just when you're using certain Ajax events and need to affirm that the user clicks? The reason I had it in this statement is because my developer put in at the end of another link_to statement.

Comment: @KishoreEechambadi You want to use an AJAX call when you need something from the server, but you don't want to reload the DOM.